# Silent error when trying to iterate through a csv file (python)

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I'm trying to make some script to use a source csv file, compare it with another one and replace lines that have the same first column in the second file using the first one.

I'm using that code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import csv
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
t = open(sys.argv[2], 'wt')
r = open(sys.argv[2], 'rt')
try:
    patch = csv.reader(f)
    panorama = csv.reader(r)
    target = csv.writer(t)
#   row2 = 0
    for row in patch:
#       print row[0]
        for row2 in panorama:
            print row
            print row[0], row2[0]
            if row[0] == row2[0]:
                target.writerow((row[0], row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8]))
finally:
    f.close()
    t.close()
    r.close()
```

Unfortunately, that fails without any errors, but my debug prints doesn't print anything. The first commented print is properly working and prints the first column of my first file.

Could you please help me to find what's wrong with this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach. The first is openning the same file for read/write (it can be done with help of module such as `fileinput`, but it will be messy because of no csv support). The second problem is you have nested for loop. After the first row of `patch`, you already exhausted the `panorama` file. What you need is two non-nested loops. Here is my approach:

```
import csv
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as patch_file, \
            open(sys.argv[2], 'rt') as pano_file, \
            open(sys.argv[3], 'wt') as output_file:

        patch_lookup = {row[0]: row for row in csv.reader(patch_file)}
        pano = csv.reader(pano_file)
        output = csv.writer(output_file)

        for row in pano:
            row = patch_lookup.get(row[0], row)
            output.writerow(row)
```

In my solution, `patch_lookup` is a dictionary where the key is the first field and value is the whole row. While reading the `pano`, the following line will look up the row in the patch and replace it if applicable:

```
        row = patch_lookup.get(row[0], row)
```

After the look up, we will write the rows to the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help that allowed me to properly understand what was wrong and how to solve this. To complete the same program, how can I add at the end of the output file lines that were not found in the pano file but were in the patch file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the same file as a read-only and write-only at the same time.

> 7.2. Reading and Writing Files
>   open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).
>   mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased).

in  [Python 2.7.11 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html%20wt)

When you declare target = csv.writer(t), with t such that t = open(sys.argv[2], 'wt'), you overwrite your file pointed with sys.argv[2], and therefore, you then have nothing to compare against when you try to read panorama = csv.reader(r), with r = open(sys.argv[2], 'rt').

Answer (score 0):

Do not open the same file using both read and write - because once you issue write, contents will be gone.
Create a another file to write into.